# Cmder - <tab> does not recognize wildcards like cmd.exe in windows

Tags: cmder

On the command prompt on windows if in the current directory if there is a single `*.txt` (say `test.txt`) file then typing in `*.txt` followed by `<TAB>` will result in cmd.exe expanding the full file name to `test.txt`.

is there a trick to update `clink_inputrc_base` in the clink folder so that it could mimic this behavior?

Comment: Read clink docs or ask clink's author?

Comment: Any idea where one can find clink docs, maybe i am looking at the wrong location but the .md file in the GitHub page doesn't have anything https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/clink.md

Comment: I suppose you have the only option: https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues

Comment: The clink docs are still work-in-progress and an issue has already been posted. See my answer below for full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately not yet. (If you must use the *cmd.exe* emulated terminal in cmder)**

This is currently an open issue on the Github repository. For more detailed technical discussion on why, see the following link to the relevant Github issue:

https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/30

At present, the closest you can get to this behaviour is via the `dir` command. For example, to list all the text files in a directory you can still use `dir *.txt`.

**However, if you are willing to use the *bash* terminal emulator in *cmder* then it does work as expected.**

I just verified that if you create a new console of type `{bash::bash}`, i.e. a bash emulator console, then it gives exactly the behaviour you request. For example if there is 1 .txt file in a directory and you type `notepad *.txt` it will expand to the full name when you press tab. If there are multiple .txt files and you press tab twice, it will list all the .txt files.

If you aren't sure how to create this type of console, it can be selected from the first drop down box in the 'Create new console' dialog box.